# Summarizing by group and finding the sum in column

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has columns such as "`department`", "`hours`" and "`task`". The "`task`" column has some cells that are equal zero and other cells that are greater than zero. I would like to group the data by "`department`" and sum the amount of hours where "`task`" = `0` and sum amount of hours where "`task`" > `0`. I used the below code but I am getting `N/A`s.

```
task_hour <- df %>%

  group_by(department) %>%

  summarise(task_hour = sum(hours)[task > 0] ,
        Non_task_hour = sum(hours)[task = 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of mistakes -

1. Subset `hours` before `sum`.
2. Use `==` for comparison.

```
library(dplyr)

task_hour <- df %>%
              group_by(department) %>%
              summarise(task_hour = sum(hours[task > 0]),
                        Non_task_hour = sum(hours[task == 0]))
```

Comment: It's still showing no hours for Non_task_hour

Comment: Then you may need to provide a reproducible example of your data to debug the issue.